# React jsx not returning my button in async function

Tags: reactjs, async-await

```
  const addButtons = (x) => {
      (async () => {
          let userHasCon = await axios.get(`route`);
          if (userHasCon.data[0].Users_Id == userId) {
            console.log(userHasCon.data[0].Users_Id)
            return <button>Remove</button>
          }
      })()
  }
```

At first I made my addButtons function async but that gave an error. So I made an anonymous async function to await my api call. The problem I am having is returning jsx in an anonymous async function is this possible?

Comment: Why not just show the button when the data has loaded using state ?

Comment: @kevin The button is going to be used to delete a comment. Only the author of the comment should be able to delete it thats why I check and show the button if the logged in user is the author.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function it wont return anything. It's actually undefined because there's no return statement.

I would actually solve your issue with state and useEffect:

```
 import React from 'react'
    
    export default function CustomSelectNew() {
    
        const [userHasCon,setUserHasCon] = useState();
    
        useEffect( async ()=> {
            const data = await axios.get('route');
            setUserHasCon(data);
        },[])
    
    
        return (
            <div>
                {userHasCon.data[0].Users_Id === userId && (
                    <button>Remove</button>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }


How about something like this instead?
```

Comment: I am trying to make a function in the same component, and a new component. After seeing your code I changed my method and am now giving the id as the return value, and comparing the 2 id's where I want to put my button.